# C# LINQ join 2 tables with where clause

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to `join` 2 tables while filtering with `where` clause.  The data looks like this:

```
Category
Name Selected
A    0
B    1
C    0

SubCategory
Name ParentCategory Selected
s1   A              0
s2   B              1
s3   B              0
```

Expected results:

```
ParentCatName SubCatName SubCatSelected
B             s2         1
B             s3         0
```

Actual results:

```
ParentCatName SubCatName SubCatSelected
B             s2         1
B             s3         1  <-- should be 0
```

The code I am using is this:

```
IEnumerable<Category> result =
    from s in subcategories
    join c in categories
    on s.Parent equals c.Name into t
    from r in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where r == null ? false : r.Selected == true
    select new Category
    {
        Name = s.Name,
        Parent = (r == null ? string.Empty : r.Name),
        Selected = r.Selected
    };
```

EDIT:  Something that helped me get clarity was to temporarily rewrite this to see the resulting data structures...

```
var result =
    from s in subcategories
    join c in categories
    on s.Parent equals c.Name into t
    from r in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        s, r
    };
```

Then I came up with the answer to the filtering of selected categories.  See my answer below..

Comment: if you want the value of whether the subcategory is selected or not, why are you using `r.Selected`, as opposed to `s.Selected`?

Comment: also, wouldn't the where clause be easier to understand if you used `where r != null && r.Selected`?

Comment: Thank you Keith.  Actually, I feel the `where` clause is more clear if I just remove the reference to `r.Selected` because it really has nothing to do with the purpose of this `where` clause, which is to filter the `join` to those records satisfying the `join`.  See my edit above, and answer to my question below.

Comment: Also notice my EDIT where I remove the `where` clause in order to review the whole data structures being returned.  Examining this result reveals where `r` is returning `null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't overcomplicate the things. What you are trying to achieve is to filter subcategories by the selected categories. You can get the desired result with the following simple query

```
var result = from s in subcategories
             join c in categories on s.Parent equals c.Name
             where c.Selected
             select s;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're setting it wrong. If `r == null` then you're setting it to `false`, otherwise you're setting it to `true` here: `r.Select == true`.

Just by reading your query it looks like you may not need that `where` clause at all.

You *probably* want something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Category> result =
    from s in subcategories
    join c in categories
    on s.Parent equals c.Name into t
    from r in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new Category
    {
        Name = s.Name,
        Parent = (r == null ? string.Empty : r.Name),
        Selected = r.Selected
    };
```

Or if you need to do the `null` check then do this:

```
IEnumerable<Category> result =
    from s in subcategories
    join c in categories
    on s.Parent equals c.Name into t
    from r in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where r != null //I added the null check here
    select new Category
    {
        Name = s.Name,
        Parent = (r.Name), //I removed the null check here
        Selected = r.Selected
    };
```

Comment: Thanks maxshuty.  As I understand, the where clause you reference is required to filter only records where the join results in data.  Without this where clause, any reference to r where null results in a null reference.  r is null where the join is not satisfied.  Yes?

Comment: I believe if I'm understanding correctly that yes `r` would be `null` in that case. So you could check that it isn't null before creating the `new Category` by doing something like this: `where r != null` to prevent a null reference. I'm not sure if you want null or if it's ok to have that that in your scenario or not. It appears it would be ok since you are doing `Parent = (r == null ? string.Empty : r.Name),` and if it's not ok then add that `where` and change `Parent = r.Name,`

Answer (score 0):

I think, your t value inculudes categoies list. t must be include subcategory list and then you can take selected value of subcategory. So you always get selected value as 1 pls try this:

```
IEnumerable<SubCategory> result =
    from c in categories
    join s in subcategories
    on c.Name equals s.Parent into t
    from r in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where r == null ? false : r.Selected == true
    select new SubCategory
    {
        Name = s.Name,
        Parent = (r == null ? string.Empty : r.Name),
        Selected = r.Selected
    };
```

OBS:I'm not try this now. But I think works.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.  So I did some more looking and came up with this...

```
IEnumerable<Category> result =
    from s in subcategories
    join c in categories.Where(f => f.Selected)
    on s.Parent equals c.Name into t
    from r in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where r == null ? false : true
    select new Category
    {
        Name = s.Name,
        Parent = s.Name,
        Selected = s.Selected,
    };
```

To filter join to only selected parent category, I have added lambda expression right to that data.

Comment: Alternatively, as pointed out in comment by @maxshuty, `where` clause can be simplified to `where r!= null`

Comment: The whole `from r in ... where ...` can be removed, since it's producing a `left outer join`, but if you want the right part to be not null, then it's a simple `inner join`.

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev.  I did accept your answer as is the most brief.  However, the answer I purpose also works, and does demonstrate possible ways to customize the results.  Bother are correct, but yours is most brief.